# SwiftUI causing AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid value type for attribute: 54808 on List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a custom List that displays values from Realm Database, however whenever I configure a .sheet property on the list such that a sheet is displayed whenever user taps on the row. However whenever I add `.sheet` the app immediately crashes causing the following error:

```
2021-07-18 11:56:15.978645+0530 mongodb-swiftui[21360:965109] [error] precondition failure: invalid value type for attribute: 54808 (saw ListView, expected PreferenceKeys)
CoreSimulator 772.1 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro (A078F6C3-6036-4065-93D4-01495735E0FA) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro
AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid value type for attribute: 54808 (saw ListView, expected PreferenceKeys).
(lldb)
```

This is my code for the custom list, I designed:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    
    @State var date:String?
    @State var title:String?
    @State var mood:String?
    @State var isOpen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.gray)
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Spacer()
                    Text(date!)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text(title!)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.title)
                    Text(mood!)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                Spacer()
                Text("Info")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isOpen.toggle()
                    }
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isOpen){
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting this error too. I solved it by delaying my lengthy operations until the app's `ContentView`'s `onAppear` was called. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to go around this error. It's a really good temporary solution. But, for the other screens, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: I figured it's a good general solution. Could you post the problem code? I might be able to help out

Comment: I actually set it up, for the other screens as well. So, that works as of now! Thanks for the fix!